# Passwords in git tree + Heroku + Github

Tags: git, github, heroku, sinatra

I have a very basic application done in Sinatra
I have deployed it in Heroku (http://frasesbarrio.heroku.com)

There is a button for sharing in Facebook and in fact it can be used as a Facebook application. For Facebook authentification, my application has its own app id and app secret (right now they are two constants in the main file of the source)

I also want to share my code in Github for everyone to enjoy.

How can I send the code **with** the app id and secret to Heroku and **without** them to Github in a maintainable fashion? (I mean that I will keep changing the app now and then, deploying and sending to Github after every change)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out [Config vars](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) - it can store id/secret separate from app code.